# Why "foreach (var NastepcyRur in context.Descendants()" don't see all Tag in xml file

Tags: c#, xml, ranorex

this is part of my xml file:

```
<PipeSelectionOptions ID="9" ClassId="108" CoTo="ODRDaneOgolneCOOP" AlreadyDumped="False">
<DobierajKsztalki Caption="Dobieraj kształtki" Value="A">True</DobierajKsztalki>
<KorygujSrednice Caption="koryguj" Value="B">True</KorygujSrednice>
<PonownieDobierajSrednice Caption="P">True</PonownieDobierajSrednice>
<PrzechodzDoNastepcowRur Caption="P">True</PrzechodzDoNastepcowRur>
<SposobWymiarowaniaWentObjesc Caption="S" Value="A">N</SposobWymiarowaniaWentObjesc>
<ZachowajNarzuconeSrednice Caption="Z">True</ZachowajNarzuconeSrednice>
<NastepcyRur Count="2">
  <ODRDaneOgolneNastepcyRurItem Index="0" ID="0" ClassId="0" AlreadyDumped="False">
    <IsAutoMetkaNastepnika Caption="">False</IsAutoMetkaNastepnika>
    <Metka Caption="" Value="R">2</Metka>
    <MetkaNastepnika Caption="" Value="R">1</MetkaNastepnika>
  </ODRDaneOgolneNastepcyRurItem>
  <ODRDaneOgolneNastepcyRurItem Index="1" ID="3" ClassId="0" AlreadyDumped="False">
    <IsAutoMetkaNastepnika Caption="">True</IsAutoMetkaNastepnika>
    <Metka Caption="" Value="R">1</Metka>
    <MetkaNastepnika Caption="" Value="(brak)">0</MetkaNastepnika>
  </ODRDaneOgolneNastepcyRurItem>
</NastepcyRur>
```

I want get to *ODRDaneOgolneNastepcyRurItem* by code:

```
foreach (XElement context in rootTemplate.XPathSelectElements("//PipeSelectionOptions"))
{
    if (context.Attribute("CoTo").Value.ToString().Equals("ODRDaneOgolneCOOP"))
    {
        foreach (var NastepcyRur in context.Descendants())
        {
            if (NastepcyRur.Name.LocalName.Equals("ODRDaneOgolneNastepcyRurItem"))
            {
                sb.Append("<li><span>Rodzina rur:</span> " + NastepcyRur.Element("Metka").Attribute("Value").Value.ToString() + ";<span> Nastpca rur:</span> " + NastepcyRur.Element("MetkaNastepnika").Attribute("Value").Value.ToString() +"</li>");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

..but foreach (second) finish on *ZachowajNarzuconeSrednice*, don't see NastepcyRur and children of NastepcyRur .  Why?

Comment: NastepcyRur.Name.LocalName.Equals("ODRDaneOgolneNastepcyRurItem")) this never happen in your code. which is not like it's not reaching the node :-)

Comment: i suggest you to write some English samples not Polish. then you will get some more responses in shorter time. :-)

Comment: It only has attributes.  Do you really mean NastepcyRur which has child elements?

Comment: Your code finds both elements when I try it, having added an outer root element. Please provide a [mcve].